# How to recal unique text using java div class

Tags: java, css, class, html

I'd like to make one text for multiple html files, something like greating. Let's say greating is:

> "Hello, if you have any questions please conatact me."

What I want is to recall that text on every html page. And later if I change it, the change would appear on all the html pages.

I am weak on java, but I think I need to create some javascript and recall the text with div class function, like the facebook button is made.

P.S. Facebook button recall:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-  layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

with javascript you can change the content of a tag with html() function, or you could include the resource, i guess it depends on the technology being used

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest form, you can create a function in your javascript master copy and make a document.write call. You would need to call that script file on every page.

```
function greetingMessage() {

   document.write('your message); 

};
```

Then

```
call greetingMessage();
```

you can also put the javascript in a master file and then have the div in each HTML page:

```
 function greetingMessage(){

    document.getElementById('Message').innerHTML = 'Your Message';

 };
```

HTML:

```
 <body onload="greetingMessage();">

     <div id="Message" style="color:red;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JSP's or Servlets you can have a resource/properties file that contains many Strings being used throughout your application.  The properties file would contain key=value pairs.  You could then simply reference a particular key in the properties file, for instance:

> > > greeting=Hello, if you have any questions please contact me

The key is "greeting", the value is "Hello, if you have any questions please contact me"

To read in the properties file you would use the Properties class like so:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class MyWebPage extends HttpServlet
{
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
  {
     PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
     response.setContentType("text/html");
     out.print("<html><head></head><body><div class=\"someclass\">" +
        getGreeting() + "</div>"
     "</body></html>"                   
     );
  }

  public String getGreeting()
  {
    String greeting = "";
    try{
      Properties prop = new Properties();
      InputStream input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");

      // load a properties file
      prop.load(input);

      greeting = prop.getProperty("greeting");

      input.close();
   }
   catch(IOException ioe){ioe.printStackTrace();}
   finally{
       if (input != null)
       {
         try {
           input.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
    }

    return greeting;
  }
}
```

The same sort of thing can be effectively used in Java Server Pages.  Hope this helps.